# Can't get RDoc to suppress cross-references for a specific word

Tags: ruby, rake, rdoc

I'm using the jeweler gem when developing new gems. As part of the skeleton, it sets up a set of RDoc related rake tasks - the main one being `rake rdoc`. As far as I can tell from the Rakefile, this task uses the `rake/rdoctask` library to generate HTML documentation from my RDoc comments.

It tries intelligently to make references to classes and methods inside my RDoc comments. But since I for instance have a method called `user`, every time I write `user` the RDoc generator thinks I'm referencing this method. According to the [RDoc manual](http://rdoc.rubyforge.org/RDoc.html) (at the very end of 'Documenting Source Code'), this can be disabled by prefixing the word with a backslash (\) - e.g. `\user`.

But in my case this doesn't work. It simply just outputs the backslash in the finished HTML document and still uses the word as a cross-reference.

Any idea of how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have an old version of RDoc installed, try updating to the 2.5 branch with

`gem install rdoc -v "~>2.5"`